# Is there a recommend way to get data back from a C++ POCO Task, data allocated to a private std::vector member is deleted

Tags: c++, poco-libraries

I would like to get data out of a C++ POCO Library Task class, however after the runTask() function finishes any dynamic memory variables are disposed of seemingly. In the following example _series will be empty once runTask() completes, and so getSeries() returns nothing.

```
#include <Poco/Task.h>
#include <Poco/TaskManager.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class FibonacciTask: public Poco::Task
{
public:
    FibonacciTask(int n): Task("FibonacciTask"), _n(n) {}

    void runTask()
    {
        long long a = 0, b = 1;
        _series.push_back(a);
        _series.push_back(b);

        for (int i = 2; i <= _n; i++) {
            long long temp = a + b;
            a = b;
            b = temp;
            _series.push_back(b);

            if (isCancelled()) {
                std::cout << "\nTask cancelled." << std::endl;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    const std::vector<long long>& getSeries() const { return _series; }

private:
    int _n;
    std::vector<long long> _series;
};
```

I tried using a private std::vector variable and accessing it via a getter.

Here's an example of it not working correctly:

```
> g++ -I/usr/local/include/Poco -o prog main.cpp -L/usr/local/lib -lPocoFoundation

> ./prog

0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55

0 139993720817872 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55

0 139993720817872 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55
```

```
#include <Poco/Task.h>
#include <Poco/TaskManager.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include <unistd.h>

class FibonacciTask: public Poco::Task
{
public:
    FibonacciTask(int n): Task("FibonacciTask"), _n(n) {}

    void runTask()
    {
        long long a = 0, b = 1;
        _series.push_back(a);
        _series.push_back(b);

        for (int i = 2; i <= _n; i++) {
            long long temp = a + b;
            a = b;
            b = temp;
            _series.push_back(b);

            if (isCancelled()) {
                std::cout << "\nTask cancelled." << std::endl;
                break;
            }
        }
         for (const auto& num : _series) {
          std::cout << num << " ";
         }
         std::cout << std::endl;
    }

  void printSeries(){
     for (const auto& num : _series) {
       std::cout << num << " ";
     }
     std::cout << std::endl;

  }

private:
    int _n;
    std::vector<long long> _series;
};

int main()
{
   Poco::TaskManager tm;
   FibonacciTask *ft = new FibonacciTask(10);
   tm.start(ft);

   usleep(1000) ;

   ft->printSeries() ;

   usleep(1000) ;

   tm.joinAll();

   usleep(1000) ;

   ft->printSeries() ;

   usleep(1000) ;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're going to need to show more code. I see no reason for the `_series` to just vanish unless the `FibonacciTask` has also gone out of scope.

Comment: It may be helpful to show how the `FibonacciTask` is created and run by the POCO library and how you tried to access the results

Comment: I've added a full example to the original.

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation of the [Poco::TaskManager](https://docs.pocoproject.org/current/Poco.TaskManager.html) it is stated that:

> The TaskManager takes ownership of the Task object and deletes it when it it finished.

Thus, the TaskManager will call delete on your object in `joinAll` and therefore `ft` including its `_series` will not be valid anymore.

Have a look into `std::shared_ptr` to either make the task a shared object or the series contained within it. For the task I think the library has its own `using TaskPtr = AutoPtr < Task >` which implements the same reference-counted idea. Alternatively, create the series vector outside of the task in `main` and just store a reference to it in the task object (the reference may be passed in the constructor).

Comment: But it spits out garbage before joinAll is called seemingly. This is why there are usleep calls in the example code. I'd seen this already :)

Comment: The reference via the constructor works, this is what I resorted too. Just annoying I couldn't understand why it didn't work. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: The timing is not so important, it may be when the task finishes or when the task manager decides to do its clean-up. In any case you are not the owner anymore once the task is done. Therefore you must implement a mechanism to keep the ownership, or at least of the results.